# Combining String Formats

Tags: python, string, format

I am trying to use `.format()` to format my output. I am trying to align the float to be centered, occupy a width of 12 and only display 2 decimal points.

I already have it working to be centered and occupy a width of 12 as follows:

`print "{:^12}".format(dig)`

However, how do I add the two decimal places format into this? I know it's `.2f`, but how do I combine it all? I tried adding it after the 12, before the `:` and at all sorts of places - it would always throw back an error.

Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, you can find the documentation on format specifications here: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `12.2f`:

```
>>> print "|{:^12.2f}|".format(145.6798)
|   145.68   |
```

used `|` just to prove that the `12` width is working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation for the [format specification](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
dig = 22/7.0   # 3.142857142857143

print "->123456789012<-"
print "->{:^12.2f}<-".format(dig)   # using .2f as you expected
              ^^^
```

will give you

```
->123456789012<-
->    3.14    <-
```